# Perpendicular doppler effect photons

Tags: special-relativity, photons, doppler-effect

I have a photon with frequency $f$ in the lab frame and I observe it in a inertial frame moving perpendicular to the photon. The direction of the velocity of the photon must change, but does this cause a change in the frequency in a similar way to observing in a frame with parallel velocity,
$$\nu '= \nu\frac{\sqrt{1-\beta}}{\sqrt{1+\beta}}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4-momentum transfers accordingly to Lorentz transformation, and for a photon travelling along Y axis ($\nu$ is frequency) it has such form
$$p^\mu=(h\nu, 0,h\nu,0)$$ 
Lorentz transformation for observer moving along $x$ axis is:
$$p^0\rightarrow \frac{p^0-\beta p^1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}},p^1\rightarrow \frac{p^1-\beta p^0}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}, p^2\rightarrow p^2, p^3\rightarrow p^3$$
Actually you need only first one to get frequency in a new frame:
$$\nu '= \frac{\nu}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}},$$ ($\beta$ is $\frac{v}{c}$ OFC). You could calculate the remaining components of new 4-momentum to get an angle.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about using the Lorentz transform!